# how to add caption to simple html galleria

Tags: javascript, html, galleria

I am new to html, I am simply trying to add a caption on top or below each image in the code below; inputs welcome. It seems that an additional option is needed on the line where pictures are included; i have tried alt="my image description", it adds and info link "i" on the page, but I would need to place it above or below the image.

```
 <head>
    <title> identity </title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" 
        content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <link href = "../includes/important.css" rel= "stylesheet" type ="text/css" />
    <link href="../includes/slide-out-menu-new.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css"/> 
    <script src="../includes/js/slide-out-menu-new.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="galleria/galleria-1.2.8.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../assignments/galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.css"></script>

<style>
    #galleria{ width: 700px; height: 400px; background: #000 }
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class= "name"> 
<center> <img src= "../images/main_menu_me.jpg"><center>

</div>

     <STYLE TYPE="text/css">

#menu1 { display : none }
#menu2 { display : none }
#menu3 { display : none }

A:link {color:white; text-decoration:none}
A:hover {color:yellow; text-decoration:none}

</STYLE> 
<div class="body3">


<div id="galleria">
    <img src="../images/lafete1.jpg" image title="My image title" alt="My image description">
    <img src="../images/lafete2.jpg">
    <img src="../images/lafete3.jpg">

</div>
</div> 
<script>
    Galleria.loadTheme('galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');    
    Galleria.run('#galleria');
</script>

<div class= "navigation2">
</br>
<p align="right"><a href = "../assignments/about.html"> about</a></p> 

<p align="right"><a href = "../assignments/contact.html"> contact</a></p> 

</body>

</head>
```

Answer (score 3):

From [galleria's doc's](http://galleria.io/docs/references/data/):

**Captions & meta data**
If you want to extract meta data from the HTML source such as title & description, you can provide this as  attributes:

```
<img            src="image.jpg" 
         data-title="My title" 
   data-description="My <strong>description</strong>" 
          data-link="http://my.destination.com" 
>
```

Side-note: In HTML5 one can now (by specification) add custom attributes to elements (in the HTML markup) but they must be prefixed with `data-`. That is what later versions of galleria now use.

Hope this helps!